# How to create object of a Excel Row

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot

I want to save each Row of a excel sheet as a "Upload Entity". The problem is now to order the right cell to the right attribute.

I have solved this with the switch cases.

Is there a another better way to create the object?

My Code:
UploadRow Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "upload_row")
public class UploadRow {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  ....
  //setter and getter
  ....
 }
```

RowUti.java:

```
public void readRows(){
    ...
    Cell headerCell;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        UploadRow uploadRow = new UploadRow();
        if (row != null) { 

            for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                headerCell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

                setFields(uploadRow, row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), headerCell.getStringCellValue());
            }   
        }
    }
    ...
}


public void setFields(UploadRow uploadRow, String value, String header,){
    switch (header) {
        case "FirstName":
            uploadRow.setFirstName(value);
            break;
        case "LastName":
            uploadRow.setLastName(value);
            break;
        ...
        default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid cell value " + value);
    }
}
```

Thx in advance

Comment: What is the error? What do you mean by "does not refrences to the same object"? Are you overwriting `uploadRow` before saving it to your database?

Comment: i solved this: uploadRow = setFields(...)

Comment: [Any method declared void doesn't return a value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html), so did you perhaps change `public void setFields(..` to `public UploadRow setFields(..` and add a `return` statement?

Comment: yeah now i return UploadRow